# Problemas com get_blob usando Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

Salvei uma imagem, convertendo ela em um *array de bytes*, em uma coluna no *Sqlite* com tipo de dado *byte*.
Quando faço um cursor para buscar esta imagem do banco utilizando a classe *Cursor* e o método `get_blob()`, diz que não pode converter.

O que estou a fazer de errado?

```
public List<Locais> listaDeMemorias() {

    DataBaseApp dtbApp = new DataBaseApp( this );
    SQLiteDatabase dtb = dtbApp.getReadableDatabase();

    try {
        Cursor c = dtb.rawQuery("select idLocal,dsLocal,dtVisita,dsObservacoes,imagem from Locais", null);
        Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("Tem dados");

            int id = c.getInt( 0 );
            System.out.println( "ID: " + id );

            byte[] imgData = c.getBlob(4);

            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( imgData, 0,  imgData.length);


            Locais locais = new Locais(c.getInt(0),c.getString(1),new Timestamp( c.getLong( 2 )),c.getString(3),img);

            System.out.println( "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" );
            listaLocais.add(locais);
        }


        return listaLocais;

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    } finally {
        dtb.close();
    }

    System.out.println( "Enviando lista de locais: " + listaLocais.size() );

    return listaLocais;
}
```

Comment: Mostre como está a utilizar o método `get_blob`.

Comment: Um erro comum na utilização dos métodos *get* da classe *Cursor* tem haver com a correta indexação dos campos. No seu caso está a fazê-la corretamente.

Comment: Não sei o q pode ser! Ele cai na exception bem naquela linha q chama o get_blob

Comment: Como está a declarar a coluna *imagem*

Comment: Tipo de dado: bytea

Comment: *Byte* ou *Blob*?

Comment: "bytea", é um tipo de dado do sqlite

Comment: Não conheço esse tipo. Veja a minha resposta.

Comment: Vou tentar mudar pra vê c da certo! Aviso c ser!

Comment: A mensagem q da é a seguinte: INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob

Comment: Mostre o código onde converte para array byte e aquele que grava.

Comment: Consegui! Mudei a coluna no sqlite para blob. Mas o problema não era este, no momento de inserir no banco eu estava inserindo outra informação na coluna imagem. Revisei o código e achei.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas razões, segundo a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getBlob%28int%29), para o método `getBlob()` lançar uma excepção:

> o valor é nulo ou o campo não é *Blob*

Partindo do principio que não é nulo então é porque a coluna esta mal definida.

Você diz na pergunta *"em uma coluna no Sqlite com tipo de dado byte."*

Não sei se é possível declarar um coluna como *byte* mas se foi assim que a declarou o problema está aí.

A coluna para poder receber um *array de bytes* tem de ser declarada como *Blob*

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, imagem BLOB, ..., ...);
```